# How to use Rider on Ubuntu for creating C# projects?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, rider

I've already read advices about installing mono and dotnet.All of them are useless.

I want to run my simple C# console application on Rider.

[image: My settings]

Maybe there is a conflict between mono msbuild and dotnet-msbuild  i dunno. He just cant see the references like "System".

How can i fix it? Anyone has solved this problem yet?

Log files here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EgciAZL0q30M9oqwipgQT8T3l6AOHG98/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: As far as I can see you have too old xbuild... Maybe you have to update mono and use MsBuild instead of xbuild...

Comment: @xtmq, actually there is no such thing as MsBuild.exe in mono directiories. There is only MsBuild.dll but it doesnt work too

Comment: Rider detects msbuild (dll/exe whatever) from mono automaticly, see https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/208074835-Using-Project-Rider-on-Mac-prerequisites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If simple updating mono doesn't help, then Log files from Ride Help -> Show log files may contain answers )
Share the whole directory zipped.

Comment: Done. Check changes in the post